# Using np.any() to capture outliers

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to pull all upper and lower outliers from a data frame. I can do it in separate lines, assigning a variable to the uppers (ex. `hi_outs = (sepal_outliers > 4.05)`) and another variable to the lowers (ex. `lo_outs = (sepal_outliers < 2.05)`). But I wanted to try and grab both in one variable.

```
sepal_outliers = x[:,1]
outliers = np.any(sepal_outliers < 2.05, sepal_outliers > 4.05)
df[outliers]
```

I'm not sure why I've gotten the following error.

`TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index`

any thoughts? How might I make this work? I'll keep reading up in the meantime...

Comment: mcve - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve?

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.any.html#numpy.ndarray.any) for `np.any`?  You can't pass two separate conditions like that.

Comment: Yes i did but I suppose I didn't quite understand it. the documentation is not always clear to us newbies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use NumPy's boolean indexing:

```
outliers = sepal_outliers[(sepal_outliers < 2.05) | (sepal_outliers > 4.05)]
```

That is, construct the boolean array of `True` or `False` for each element of the condition you set and index into the same array, `sepal_outliers` with it.
Note that for this, you need `sepal_outliers` to be a NumPy array rather than a common-or-garden Python list.

Comment: Well that's interesting. Thanks. It seems that this creates a list of the outliers which I can convert to a data frame. But the original code just prints the rows containing the outliers, index and all. Any thoughts on how to do that? Thanks, I will definitely put this idea in my toolbox.